# How to stack the dataframe rows into different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have data in the following format:

```
| depth | density | tb10 | tb18 |
|-------|---------|------|------|
|   1   |   10    |  210 |  220 |
|   2   |   10    |  245 |  255 |
|   3   |   10    |  275 |  285 |
|   4   |   10    |  295 |  305 |
|   1   |   20    |  215 |  225 |
|   2   |   20    |  250 |  260 |
|   3   |   20    |  280 |  290 |
|   4   |   20    |  300 |  310 |
```

however, i want the data in the following way.

```
| depth | density | den10_tb10 | den10_tb18 | den20_tb10 | den20_tb18|
|-------|---------|------      |------      |------      |------     |
|   1   |   10    |  210       |  220       |    215     |   225     |           
|   2   |   10    |  245       |  255       |    250     |   260     |
|   3   |   10    |  275       |  285       |    280     |   290     |
|   4   |   10    |  295       |  305       |    300     |   310     |
```

I tried pivot table, but could not do it properly.

Comment: please consider puting numerical example with code of data so we can regenerate the data. and explain further what you trying to do  (want the data  following way) what is it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using Pivot table

```
df_pivoted= df.pivot(index='depth', columns='density')
df_pivoted.columns = [f'den{den}_{col}' for col, den in df_pivoted.columns]
```

You can always get exactly the same output by reordering the columns, even though you don't need to do this if you gonna use your dataframe in further operations.

```
df_pivoted = df_pivoted[['den10_tb10', 'den10_tb18', 'den20_tb10', 'den20_tb18']]
```